# JDialog não mostra JLabel

Tags: java, swing

Eu criei uma classe chamada JDialogProgress, mas quando eu "chamo ela" o objeto JLabel não mostra na tela.

Estou chamando assim:

```
    JDialogProgress Progress = new JDialogProgress(new JFrame(), false);
    Progress.setVisible(true);
    for(long i=0;i<299999; i++)
       System.out.print(i);
    Progress.setVisible(false);
    Progress.dispose();
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
package prototipoassdig;

public class JDialogProgress extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public JDialogProgress(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        update(getGraphics()); 
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jLabel1.setText("TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE");
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 186, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(93, 93, 93)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(102, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pack();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JDialogProgress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JDialogProgress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JDialogProgress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JDialogProgress.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JDialogProgress dialog = new JDialogProgress(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
}
```

Comment: Acredito que se você colocar uma imagem da sua janela JDialog em funcionamento ajuda a quem se interessar em responder.

Answer (score 1):

Estranho para min apareceu a JLabel escrita TESTE TESTE TESTE

Verifica sua versão do Java e caso não era essa sua duvida esclareça.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]